# Как рендерится tiledMap? LibGDX

Tags: libgdx

Есть карта созданная в Tiled.
Ширина/высота 40х40.
Видимая область (область камеры просмотра карты) 10х10.
Как происходит отрисовка карты при:

```
mapRenderer.setView(camera);  
mapRenderer.render();
```

Только то что попадает в камеру 10x10, или же все 40х40 спрайтов отрисовываются даже за камерой ?
Или же это настраивается ?

Answer (score 0):

[В документации сказано](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/MapRenderer.html#setView-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera-), что так же задаются границы, в которых выводится карта.

[Так же на GitHub можно найти сам код](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/renderers/OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer.java#L77-L89), который рендерит, и увидеть что рендерит только те тайлы которые вхоядт в карту

Так что ответ на вопрос - да, выводит только те которые входят в камеру. Замечу, что выводит только ТАЙЛЫ которые входят в камеру. Если же размер тайла больше клетки - его не будет видно.

Comment: Спасибо!
"Если же размер тайла больше клетки - его не будет видно." - вот тут не понял.

Comment: Размер текстуры может быть больше чем размер клетки

Comment: ну так она и так больше, она же масштабируется под размер клетки.

Comment: Имееться в веду случаи, когда одна клетка вылазит на другую.